# Is it okay to ask teaching questions?

Tags: discussion

I recently learned there is a stack site [dedicated to math educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions). I lurked around a little and found some very, very interesting questions (such as [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-is-a-good-handwriting-font-for-mathematics)).

I am no teacher at all (I'd like to become one though) but I think that there are some among the frequent users of this board. I also think that sharing experience on how to explain our beloved EE would be great because teaching a subject is one of the (if not the) most noble things you could do. This *is* a teach 'n learn board after all.

I don't have any particular example question in mind, I can try to think of some though, I was thinking of something like "Do you think that analogy X is good for concept Y" or "Usually A is taught before B but for x, y and z I think it should be the opposite".

I know you guys are already screaming "Primarily opinion based you fool!" but I actually read the help center and  the last section, that I copy here for you, gives me some hope:

> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be
>   constructive.** What does that mean? Constructive subjective
>   questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Do you think that a "teaching question" would be on topic? If yes, do you feel that some sort of limitations or rules should apply? Which ones?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, questions on how to teach some aspect of electrical engineering are on topic.  We don't get many questions like that, but there have been some good ones that were well received and well up-voted.  For example:

[Illustrating op amp feedback without control theory](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/50460/4512)
[Design a cheap 1.5V / 12V DC motor driver for high school students](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/83155/4512)
[What is / how can I get a student-safe power supply for electronics projects?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/56578/4512)

To avoid the question being too opinion-based, make sure to ask something specific.  For example, *"How do I keep students interested to get to how transistors work?"* is too open ended, but *"What would be a good experiment to demonstrate in front of a class to show how a BJT works?"* would be better.

Comment: I agree that these questions are mostly a good thing. The biggest danger to "teaching" questions is that it's really easy to make the scope too wide for the StackExchange format.

Comment: thanks Olin. that's what I suspected. I guess that the asker should be smart enough to ask an answerable question.